# VSCode DefinitionProvider in JavaScript/Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vscode-extensions

I would like to implement a DefinitionProvider in my VSCode Extension.
But I'm not sure how I have to do this in Javascript, because the registerDefinitionProvider does not accept my class.

```
module.exports = class ALDefinitionProvider {
    provideDefinition(textDocument, position, token) {
        console.log(textDocument);
        console.log(position);
    }
}
```

The error message:
[image]
Here the text:
Argument of type 'ALDefinitionProvider' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DefinitionProvider'.
The types returned by 'provideDefinition(...)' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ProviderResult<Location | Location[] | LocationLink[]>'.

And I registered it like this:

```
vscode.languages.registerDefinitionProvider('al', new ALDefinitionProvider());
```

I also tried something like this, but I'm not sure how to implement it with this:

```
class GoDefinitionProvider extends vscode.DefinitionProvider {
    provideDefinition(
        document: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position, token: vscode.CancellationToken):
        Thenable<vscode.Location> {
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to implement this in Javascript/Node.js? :)

Comment: "*registerDefinitionProvider does not accept my class*" - what's the error you are getting?

Comment: @Bergi I added the error message to my question :)

Comment: So this is a typescript error! Yes, you will need to change the type of the `providedDefinition` method to return a `Location` (or an array of it, or `LocationLink`s). "*I'm not sure how to implement it with this*" - would you know how to implement it otherwise? And what definitions do you *want* your extension to provide?

Comment: oh well, my fault...
I returned the Location with a Promise and it worked.
"And what definitions do you want your extension to provide?" - Variables and Functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, was my fault...
I added a Promise to my function and now it works!

```
module.exports = class ALDefinitionProvider {
    provideDefinition(textDocument, position, token) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            console.log(textDocument);
            console.log(position);
            return new Location(Uri.parse(''), position);
        });
    }
}
```